# Conditional required-field validation in Serde

Tags: rust, serde

Can I specify that a field must be present (not null) if (and only if) another field has a certain value?

Here is an example (see the comment):

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct Params {
    pub id: i32,
    pub foo: i32,
    pub bar: Option<i32>, // this must be Some if "foo == 5"
}
```

I'm also interested in cases where `foo` is an enum.

Comment: Your real usecase isn't visible so it's hard to answer you but it's probable your structure isn't well designed and is missing an enum which would force the type's values to always be consistent

Answer (score 2):

You can only perform validation by manually implementing `Deserialize`. You can still use the derive to perform the heavy lifting:

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(remote = "Self")]
pub struct Params {
    pub id: i32,
    pub foo: i32,
    pub bar: Option<i32>, // this must be Some if "foo == 5"
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Params {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        let this = Self::deserialize(deserializer)?;

        if this.foo == 5 && this.bar.is_none() {
            return Err(D::Error::custom("bar should be set when foo equals '5'"));
        }

        Ok(this)
    }
}
```

Another option is to have two structs, one to deserialize (`ParamsUnchecked`) and a second which is checked that all constraints hold (`Params`). You can then use `TryFrom` to convert between them.

```rust
#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
#[serde(try_from = "ParamsUnchecked")]
pub struct Params {
    pub id: i32,
    pub foo: i32,
    pub bar: Option<i32>, // this must be Some if "foo == 5"
}

#[derive(Deserialize, Debug)]
pub struct ParamsUnchecked {
    pub id: i32,
    pub foo: i32,
    pub bar: Option<i32>,
}

impl TryFrom<ParamsUnchecked> for Params {
    type Error = String;
    
    fn try_from(pu: ParamsUnchecked) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        if pu.foo == 5 && pu.bar.is_none() {
            return Err("bar should be set when foo equals '5'".to_string());
        }
        Ok(Self {
            id: pu.id,
            foo: pu.foo,
            bar: pu.bar,
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: The first approach doesn't quite work as is - `conflicting implementations of trait \`Deserialize<'_>\` for type \`Params\``

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by writing your own deserializer.

This is how the code works in a few bullet points:

1. Use a struct `InnerParams` with all the same fields like `Params` and make it derive `Deserialize`, so you don't have to write that by hand.
2. Deserialize using the code generated for `InnerParams`
3. Do your custom validation on the deserialzied `InnerParams`, when they're invalid return a custom error
4. If valid map to `Params`

Code:

```rust
use serde::de::Error;
use serde::{Deserialize, Deserializer, Serialize};

#[derive(Serialize, Debug)]
pub struct Params {
    pub id: i32,
    pub foo: i32,
    pub bar: Option<i32>, // this must be Some if "foo == 5"
}

impl<'de> Deserialize<'de> for Params {
    fn deserialize<D>(deserializer: D) -> Result<Self, D::Error>
    where
        D: Deserializer<'de>,
    {
        // Create our contract for internal use
        #[derive(Deserialize)]
        struct InnerParams {
            id: i32,
            foo: i32,
            bar: Option<i32>,
        }

        // Deserialize the contract
        let inner = InnerParams::deserialize(deserializer)?;

        // Do the additional validation, if it fails return an error
        if inner.foo == 5 && inner.bar.is_none() {
            return Err(D::Error::custom("bar should be set when foo equals '5'"));
        }

        // Return the actual contract
        Ok(Params {
            id: inner.id,
            foo: inner.foo,
            bar: inner.bar,
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but, honestly, I was hoping for something simple, declarative. If I had to write a custom deserializer like that, I would rather simply write a few lines of codes that validate the parsed `Params` value directly.

Comment: As far as I know this is the only way to do it using serde, since serde is a serialize/deserialize library, not a validation library.

Comment: To add some context the discussion on [this issue](https://github.com/serde-rs/serde/pull/1858) pretty well lays out the reasoning.